# Рассчитать результат значений в массиве

Tags: javascript, функции, foreach

Всем привет! В массиве размещены результаты спортивных событий. Победа, ничья и проигрыш дают соответственно 3, 1 и 0 балла. Нужно высчитать из данных в массиве, сколько очков заработала команда.
По логике нужно методом `forEach` перебрать весь массив и через условные операторы вывести результат. Видимо, где-то допустил ошибку и функция не работает корректно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка и что исправить?
Спасибо.

```js
let arr1 = ['100:90', '110:98', '100:100', '95:46', '54:90', '99:44', '90:90', '111:100'];

function countPoints(score) {
    let points;
    score.forEach(function(el) {
      let i = 0;
      let each = parseInt(el[i].split(':'));
      if(each[0] > each[1]){
        return points += 3;
      } else if(each[0] === each[1]){
        return points += 1
      } else {
        return points +=0;
      }
    }); 
  return points;
}

console.log(countPoints(arr1));
```

Comment: ошбика в `el[i].split(':')` посмотрите что вы в итоге получаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr1 = ['100:90', '110:98', '100:100', '95:46', '54:90', '99:44', '90:90', '111:100'];

function countPoints(score) {
  let points = 0;
  score.forEach(function(el) {
    let each = el.split(':').map(Number);
    if (each[0] > each[1]) {
      points += 3;
    } else if (each[0] === each[1]) {
      points += 1;
    }
  });
  return points;
}

console.log(countPoints(arr1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибки:

- `points` не инициализирована числовым значением, поэтому результатом суммированиия чисел с этой переменной всегда будет `NaN`
- сплит первого символа строки (`el[i]`) здесь всегда возвращает массив с одним элементом (с этим символом) попадающим в `each[0]` - поэтому `each[1]` всегда возвращает `undefined`, и к `points` всегда прибавляется `0`
- результаты сплита не приводятся к числовым значениям, поэтому сравнение в каждом случае алфавитное (в соответствии с которым `'10' < '2'`, и т.д.)

---

Код можно значительно упростить, используя для вычисления очков одно математическое выражение (вместо двух проверок):

```js
let arr1 = ['100:90', '110:98', '100:100', '95:46', '54:90', '99:44', '90:90', '111:100'];

function countPoints(scores) {
  let points = 0;
  for (const score of scores) {
    const [left, right] = score.split(':'); 
    points += Math.floor((Math.sign(left - right) + 1) * 1.5); // += <3|1|0>
  } 
  return points;
}

console.log(countPoints(arr1));
```

`Math.sign(left - right)` возвращает знак разности (при ее вычислении, типкаст строк к числам выполняется автоматически) с единичным значением или нулем: `+1`|`0`|`-1`;
Прибавляем единицу чтобы получить `2`|`1`|`0`, соответственно;
Умножением на `1.5` с отбрасыванием дробной части результата (`Math.floor`) получаем `3`|`1`|`0`, что и требуется.
Для программера знакомого с операциями округления вниз и взятия знака, такое выражение будет читаемее "лапши" условных операторов. Комменты тоже помогают.

В целом, я бы записал еще попроще для себя (но увы, редьюс может пугать, хотя он няшка):

```
const countPoints = scores => scores.reduce((rslt, score) => {
  const [left, right] = score.split(':'); 
  return rslt += ~~((Math.sign(left - right) + 1) * 1.5); // += <3|1|0>
}, 0);
```

Если же хочется оставить на подсчете именно условия, то имхо предпочтительнее тернарник - его вроде почти все читают легко, даже начинающие:

```
points += (left > right)   ? 3
        : (left === right) ? 1
        : 0;
```

Оформление это конечно дело вкуса, в нем нет каких-то определенных правил :)